# How to safely use a password in Azure Automation

Tags: azure-automation, azure-application-gateway

I'm following this approach to automate the renewal of a Let's Encrypt certificate in Azure Application Gateway. https://intelequia.com/blog/post/1012/automating-azure-application-gateway-ssl-certificate-renewals-with-let-s-encrypt-and-azure-automation

You can see the Azure Automation Runbook that's used in here: https://github.com/intelequia/letsencrypt-aw/blob/master/letsencryptaw_v2.ps1
The problem is that the password used to create the pfx certificate is in clear text in the Runbook. Like this:

> $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Passw@rd123***" -Force -AsPlainText

Is there a way to safely use a password in here?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **Azure Key Vault** to safely use a password in Azure Automation Runbook

Create Azure Key Vault and store your password as Azure Key Vault secret

Add the access policy in the key vault with get secrets permission to the service principal you are using in Azure Runbook

Now, you can use the below command in your runbook to get the secret from the Azure Key Vault:

```
$password = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "<your-unique-keyvault-name>" -Name "your-secret-name" -AsPlainText
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, why not just use the Credential store within Azure Automation, give it a dummy username (I use "dummy"), and then access it with something like `$secPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'Secret Password').GetNetworkCredential().Password -AsPlainText -Force`? You don't need an entire key vault just for this, and you don't need another authentication and connection to an outside system?  And when you pass it directly to ConvertTo-SecureString like that, it doesn't assign (and store) it to variable in memory.